# postfix rate-limit for locally submitted mails

Tags: postfix

I would like to implement per-user rate and size limits (i.e. certain maximum number of mails/volume per hour) for all outgoing mail. So far I've implemented that via postfwd policy daemon for sasl-authenticated users. However, some users also have accounts on the box making it possible for them to send mails from their web apps using the /usr/sbin/sendmail command.

Is there any way to implement per-user rate-limiting for that case as well or is my only option to forbid submitting mails this way through `authorized_submit_users` and require submission via sasl-authenticated SMTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sendmail milter for non-smtp traffic using the `non_smtpd_milters` parameter.

If that doesn't solve it for you, the safest way is to prohibit local sendmail(1) submission and force SMTP submission.

Comment: Too bad there are no restrictions that allow the use of a policy daemon since I don't want to set up a separate milter in addition to postfwd. So I guess I can only try to disallow regular users sendmail submission and see if I get complaints...

Comment: `check_policy_service` *is* a restriction; restrictions are applied in the SMTP context.